# Problemas con Media Screen CSS3

Tags: html5, css3, responsive

Se decidió optar por descargar una plantilla HTML5 y adaptarla,al momento de editar nos dimos cuenta que hay secciones que ignoran los @media screen inferiores y solo toman el último, es decir si tengo uno de 360px otro de 480px y uno de 730px, solo me tomaría el de 730, por ejemplo:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 
  
     #banner:after {
   -moz-align-items: center;
   -webkit-align-items: center;
   -ms-align-items: center;
   background-color: #0A51913;
   background-image: url("../../images/banner360.png");
   z-index:0;
   background-size:100%;
      background-position:bottom CENTER;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
   }
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   
      
  #banner:after {
   
   -moz-align-items: center;
   -webkit-align-items: center;
   -ms-align-items: center;
   background-image: url("../../images/banner2.png");
   background-size:100%;
      background-position:top right;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   z-index:10;
    
   }
      
    }
```

Por el momento si tengo una pantalla de 360 ignora el codigo para este y usa el de 480px, y si se existe otra, ignora los primeros dos y toma el ultimo.

Comment: Usas la etiqueta meta viewport en el html?

Comment: En qué orden pones las queries? Recuerda que en CSS las últimas reglas declaradas son las que prevalecen si cumplen con las especificaciones, por lo que si está primero 360, luego 480 y, al final, 730, la que va a funcionar es la última. Comienza en orden inverso.